# How to get variables from ionic angular post?

Tags: php, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

From my backend server, i couldn't get data from $_post from ionic angular post.

Below is my code:

```
$scope.formData = {};

$scope.processForm = function(){


  $http({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://domain/contact',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    headers: {
     'Content-Type': "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
   },
    data: {
      _method: 'POST',
      name: $scope.formData.name,
      email: $scope.formData.email,
      subject: $scope.formData.subject,
      message: $scope.formData.message
    } //pass data as string

  })
    .success(function(data){
         //callback
    });

};
```

variables: name, email, subject and email couldnt be passed to backend.

Comment: replace type: 'POST', with method: 'POST',..

Comment: After changing, i receive this error on console: "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed"

Comment: send data inside $http..

Comment: Yup, it is indeed inside, after the header.

Answer (score 0):

Follow this format, it should work just fine. I did it for my ionic application. Just declare your data array as a normal var data and send it to the post. You don't need to include the method type for the data just for the http method.

```
$scope.processform = function(){
       var registerdata = {PleaId:$sessionStorage.pleaId, DefenderId:contactid,IsFaceOffUser:'YES'};
            $http({
                method: 'POST', url: 'http://apple.com:9090/Plea/UpdatePleaDefendant', 
                data: registerdata})
               .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                //whatever you want after success function
               }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log("http error:", data);
              });
}
```